# Entity Reference Image not rendered

Tags: media, entities

I have a content type with an [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field. The field references multiple images.

Using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds), I can set the display format to "entity id" and when I view the content, I get a list of IDs as expected. But when I change it to "Rendered Entity", I'd expect the rendered images, but nothing is actually rendered. This is not a CSS-issue, the rendered field has no actual HTML in it. Any ideas?

Comment: The "Rendered entity" display format should have options. How have you configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the "manage display" section of the entity you're rendering and make sure the images are set as visible items in the selected "entity view mode". By default it takes "default".

Comment: How do I do that for images? Do I need an additional module?

Comment: Hey, are you referencing image through entityreference ? only entity can be referenced through entity-reference. Reference to the entity which holds the multiple image field. Or if you don't want that field to be in separate entity, don't use entity reference and rather attach the field to the current entity. Am I getting too much technical for you ?